# Objectify NotFoundException

Tags: objectify

Why do these 2 fetches result in a NotFoundException?

```
ofy().load().type(MyClass.class).id(myClassInstance.getId()).safeGet(); 
ofy().load().key(myClassInstance.getKey()).safeGet();
```

But this query returns an entity:

```
ofy().load().type(MyClass.class).filter("fieldName",myClassInstance.getUserId()).first().get();
```

Additional info:
MyClass contains a @Parent and @Id field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't specifying the parent key when loading by key.

```
ofy().load().type(MyClass.class).id(myClassInstance.getId()).safeGet();
// should be:
ofy().load().type(MyClass.class).parent(myClassInstance.getParent()).id(myClassInstance.getId()).safeGet();
```

For the second line, I suspect your implementation of getKey() is flawed and missing the parent key.  The query works because the query is not a key lookup; it just returns whatever is in the index for the property.

Remember that ids are only unique for a particular parent.  The unique identifier for an entity is {parent, id}.  Read https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Concepts carefully.